# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 when integrating ZXing source Code

Tags: android

I am getting "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"  when integrating ZXing source Code to my application. I just downloaded ZXing source for Android and imported in my Eclipse which gives lot of compilation errors and also Dalvik error. can anyone tell me how to solve this issue? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: You will have much better luck asking these questions someplace where ZXing provides support, like: http://groups.google.com/group/zxing

Comment: I would go after those compilation errors first.

Comment: Would be far more helpful to actually paste the error in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi 
In order to solve this Dalvik error,we need to create separate workspace in eclipse and build the app there. There is no reason why should it be done like that , but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue until I realized my mistake.  I didn't include the core jar from the ZXing project.  After that I didn't get the Dalvik error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was originated after updating Eclipse and ADT in March 2011. 
In my project I am using a JAR which was producing issues to rebuild and none of the former solutions worked. It took me some days to try all , search up&down with no satisfying solution.
Apparently there was a double reference to the .jar file.

Finally I :

1. removed any references from the libraries,
2. deleted the physical file form within the application.
3. got the .jar (located in a different directory outside of the project) using "Add External Jars"
4. performed a project "clean",
5. update references into the module calling the jar with (ctrl)+(shift)+O

and it did finally compile.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the adb server and restart it.